# why can't I save inputtext value to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, parameters

**Markup**

```
<apex:page controller="HomeController">
  <apex:form >
    Day <apex:inputText value="{!strday}"/><br />
    Month <apex:inputText value="{!strmonth}"/><br />
    Year <apex:inputText value="{!stryear}"/>
    <apex:commandButton action="{!openPageTwo}" title="Open Page2" value="Open Page 2"/>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Page 1 Controller**

```
public without sharing class HomeController {
    public String strday {get;set;}
    public String strmonth {get;set;}
    public String stryear {get;set;}

    public PageReference openPageTwo(){
      system.debug('*************** day = ' + strday);
      system.debug('*************** month = ' + strmonth);
      system.debug('*************** year = ' + stryear);  
      PageReference newPage = page.page2;
        newPage.getParameters().put('day', strday);
        newPage.getParameters().put('month', strmonth);
        newPage.getParameters().put('year', stryear);
        newPage.setRedirect(true);
        return newPage;
    }
```

**Page 2 Controller**

```
public class page2{
   String day;
   String month;
   String year;
   Datetime specificDate;Datetime specificDate;
   public page2(){
     day = apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('day');
     month = apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('month');
     year = apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('year');

     specificDate = DateTime.parse(month + '/' + day + '/' + year + ' 0 09:00 AM');
  }
}
```

The page opens as desired but the parameter values are null, if I check the log the values are also null.  I can't explain why the inputtext get;set; values are not being saved and passed to the pagereference.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing ingredient, which I failed to show in the question was the that the apex:commandbutton element must be within the same apex:form tags.

Answer (score 0):

set the values in the constructor

```
public class page2{
String day;
String month;
String year;
Datetime specificDate;
public page2(){
    day = apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('day');
    month = apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('month');
    year = apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('year');
    specificDate = DateTime.parse(month + '/' + day + '/' + year +' '+ '09:00 AM');
    system.debug('@@@'+specificDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually am doing that, I just copied my code into the post wrong.  It doesn't explain why the debug's in page 1 controller are null too?  Thanks for correct though.

Comment: weird. I just copy pasted your code for page1 and made above changes in page2. it worked fine

Comment: Is there any security or browser issues to consider (I am using Firefox and a system admin account)...note no sharing in the class (adding it didn't work...)

Comment: can't think of anything. i just tried in firefox and it worked fine. what's the api version?

Comment: I found it - I was going over the code (which is a bit longer than I quoted) and stupidly the commandbutton was in a different apex form tag...feel free to emphasis the importance of this in your answer and i'll mark it.  Do you know if you can (or should) pass date's in parameters (rather than parsing it back to date on the new page?

Comment: any reason why you are using multiple forms in a single page? it causes performance issues

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57789/discussion-between-sarath-garimella-and-n34-panda).